# How to type object in a material ui select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a Select component using reactjs material ui and typescript.

However, I am getting the following typing error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

My Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, MenuItem, TextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

interface Options {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type ITextFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
  name: string;
  options: Options;
};

const SelectWrapper: React.FC<ITextFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  options,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);

  const handleChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setFieldValue(name, value);
  };

  const configSelect = {
    ...field,
    ...otherProps,
    select: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    onChange: handleChange,
    error: false,
    helperText: '',
  };

  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configSelect.error = true;
    configSelect.helperText = meta.error;
  }

  return (
    <TextField variant="outlined" {...configSelect}>
      {Object.keys(options).map(opt => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
            {opt.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default SelectWrapper;
```

The options object is composed of:

```
    {
        "id": 10053,
        "name": "Direção Defensiva – Controle de Acidentes Ambev - 2021 (Distribuição)"
    },
    {
        "id": 10052,
        "name": "Segurança na Operação de Empilhadeira – 2021"
    }
```

I understand that the problem is in the object's typing, however, I can't find the correct way to type it.
What is the correct way to type id and name for this to work?

Comment: Can i just confirm that your options is actually an object not an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, options is actually an array of objects rather than just an object. So all you would need to do is map over the options variable. You are currently using Object.keys which is what you use if you are wanting to iterate over the keys in an object.

```js
      {options.map(opt => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
            {opt.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
```